# Spring-integration Logging spEl

Tags: spring-integration

Using Spring Integration how can we use the spEL to display the header and payload :

```
     <int:message-history/>
     <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" expression="'Id:' + payload.id + '; Date:' + payload.createdAt + '; FromUser: ' + payload.fromUser + '; Content: ' + payload.text"  level="INFO" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `expression` is correct.
Now you build the String using SpEL with several properties of `payload`.

To do the same for `headers` you should use the same for specific `headers` SpEL variable:

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" expression="'Id:' + headers.id + '; Date:' + headers.timestamp"  level="INFO" />
```

Any provided header is available from here.